# How to differentiate the dict key and values based on delimiters

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of type `x={'a':'1','b':'2','c;0':'a1;b1;b2;b3;b4','c;1':'a2;b2;b3;b4;b5;b6'}`

i am writing program like this

```
for key,values in x.iteritems():
   if key.split(";") is True:
      print key,value
   else:
      print key,value
```

its not working properly.

in output what i want on execution of

```
if key.split(";") is False
   print key,values
```

output should be

```
a 1
b 2
```

in output what i want on execution of

```
if key.split(";") is True
   print key,values
```

output should be

```
c;0  a1;b1;b2;b3;b4,
c;1  a2;b2;b3;b4;b5;b6
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't really need any `if`/`else` condition since you're printing key/value pairs for both cases:

```
>>> for k, v in x.iteritems():
...     print k, v
a 1
b 2
c;1 a2;b2;b3;b4;b5;b6
c;0 a1;b1;b2;b3;b4
```

Looking at the output you provided, the only difference I see is that your example is ordered. If that's what you're looking for then, you can use `sorted` like this:

```
>>> for k, v in sorted(x.iteritems()):
...     print k, v
a 1
b 2
c;0 a1;b1;b2;b3;b4
c;1 a2;b2;b3;b4;b5;b6
```

I hope this helps.